# Where to define class with both template and non-template members?

Tags: c++, class, templates

I know template definitions should all go into the header file [1]. But what to do if I have both templates and non-templates in a class:

```
// cls.h
class cls {
public:
    template <typename U> void bar(U x);   // template
    void baz();                            // non-template
    template <typename V> class nest {
    };
};

// foo1.cpp
#include "cls.h" ...

// foo2.cpp
#include "cls.h" ...
```

Ideally I want to define `bar` and `baz` in the same file as they are so closely related.

- But if I chuck all the implementation in the header, I'll end up multiply defining `baz`.
- If I chuck all the implementation into a `.cpp`, then definitions for `bar` and `nest` can't be seen by `foo1.cpp` or `foo2.cpp`.

Do I have to split `bar` and `baz` between seperate files?

[1]  *Declaring templates as `inline` doesn't seem work for me on MSVC++ using NVCC to compile CUDA code.*

Comment: What you mean by declaring templates as inline? As per the current answer, define the non-templated baz as inline and it should work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But if I chuck all the implementation in the header, I'll end up multiply defining baz.

You can still mark the function definition for `baz()` as `inline`. That will allow you to put the definition of `baz()` in a header file without leading to multiple symbol definition errors.

> If I chuck all the implementation into a .cpp, then definitions for bar and nest can't be seen by foo1.cpp or foo2.cpp.

If you know in advance what types your function template is going to be instantiated with, you can use explicit instantiations in the `.cpp` files that contain the definitions of your function templates.

```
template void cls::bar(int);
```

If none of the above options are OK for you, then you will have to give up this requirement:

> Ideally I want to define bar and baz in the same file as they are so closely related.

And put the definition of member function templates in the header file, and the definition of non-template member functions in a `.cpp` file.

Comment: Thanks - inlining the non-templated code does the trick. But will that cause bloat/longer compile times by having more stuff in the header?

Comment: And it also raises the question how exactly do compiler handle `inline` code - how are we able to multiply define `inline` functions?

Comment: Yes. But the alternative is to put baz in to the cpp. You can always put anything that is not templated in the cpp as you would normally do.

Comment: Also, what if `baz` cannot be `inline`d (e.g. recursive calls to itself)?

Comment: @MiloChen: The `inline` keyword does not have anything to do with inlining in that sense. It is mostly a way to circumvent the One Definition Rule and allow putting definitions in header files.

Comment: @MiloChen: It will increase compilation time, yes, but that's the only way could have the definitions of all the member functions in the same file. OR, as suggested in the answer, you could put everything in a `.cpp` file and use explicit instantiation, but you would have to know all possible instantiations of those templates in advance. Otherwise, you have to put something in the header and something in the `.cpp`. These are your three choices.